# 3dsmax V-ray render 'smooth' background

Tags: 3ds-max

I have a question about V-ray rendering, based on the picture:

[image]

How to create such 'smooth' background, where you can't tell where the ground ends and where bg(or wall) begins? I know, that I can just set enviromental background color to gray and use no ground plane, buy then how to keep all reflections and shadows on the ground(there is no ground then)?

When I use 'studio setup' there is always a gradient somewhere behind on edge chamfer, like here:
[image]

Do you have any good method to achieve such 'smooth' result without gradients?

Answer (score 3):

Make a extruded background that looks like this:

[image]

It emulates the way photoshoots do it. Alternatively if you want evenmore controll give this background a matte shader thatway it will only catch shadows from objects and reflections, so you can comp it on a differentbackgroud if need be.

Comment: I am using extruded background but still i get this nasty gradient. So i was looking for 'trick' to avoid this gradient

Comment: @VraySquishy The gradient is largely how you light your scene. But like ie said use a matte shader then you can just have a uniform background. Dont use a infinite light.

Answer (score 1):

Quick and dirty solution: just use a really large studio setup.

In your teapot image there's a gradient because that's where the ground "bends" into a wall, so you see shadows where the (spot) light ends. If you use a larger setup where the curve is further away from your object and you use an infinite light source you probably won't have that gradient.

You can probably also use photoshop / alpha channels / separate render for shadow, object and reflections to make the background smooth.

Comment: Well I will try infinite bg and light, maybe it wiil do the work

Answer (score 1):

You might learn something from studio photography here. To avoid shading or shadows falling on to a seamless white backdrop, it is usually specially lit with diffuse lighting. So if you can set up  a couple of diffuse light sources, pointing at the background, it might help.

For example, I'm sure you get the general idea

[image]